# extract strings from txt file in r

Tags: r, stringr

Below is a portion of large text file -

```
TABLE OF CONTENTS                        Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition Item 9.01. Financial Statements and Exhibits SIGNATURES EXHIBIT INDEX EXHIBIT 99.1     
Table of Contents        Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition         On January 27, 2005, SanDisk Corporation issued a press release
```

I want to extract - " Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition         On January 27, 2005" after second Table of Contents as there are two table of contents.

For each "Item + Number + A group of words", there is a date (in this case January 27, 2005) that I want to extract.  Basically, there are many such lines starting with Item such as Item 5.02. Departure of Directors or Principal Officers (which is without a date) or Item 5.03. Amendments to Articles of Incorporation of Bylaws; Change in Fiscal Year On April 5, 2006. I want to extract all of them that starts with "Item". Note that all of these "Item" should be after second Table of contents as mentioned above. For each "Item", even if the date is missing, I want to extract that and report the date is missing (such as NA).

I am not sure how I need to write the regular expression to extract them. I write the following, but it did not work -

```
str_extract_all(text, "Item[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.")
```

Comment: Can you provide `text` in a reproducible format and show expected output for it?

Comment: @RonakShah my data is the txt file and I want  for example "Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition January 27, 2005" Actually I want all texts that starts with Item, then number (here 2.02), then a group of words (here Results of Operations and Financial Condition ) and the date after the above line.

Comment: @RonakShah do you know how can i write a regular expression to extract a word (e.g. Item here) followed by number (2.02. here) followed by a group of words (Results of Operations and Financial Condition here) and the first date after this (January 27, 2005 here). Then I think I will get my desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
# assume each line is a single variable called "input_string"

read_csv() %>% filter(str_detect(input_string, "Table of Contents") %>% 
 mutate(newstring = str_trim(
                 str_remove(input_string, "Table of Contents")
                  )
)
```

What you want should be in newstring...

Comment: actually I create line for understanding , but the data is a txt file. There should be no line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
string <- 'TABLE OF CONTENTS                        Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition Item 9.01. Financial Statements and Exhibits SIGNATURES EXHIBIT INDEX EXHIBIT 99.1     
Table of Contents        Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition         On January 27, 2005, SanDisk Corporation issued a press release'

stringr::str_extract(string, 'Item \\d+\\.\\d+.*?\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}')
#[1] "Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition         On January 27, 2005"
```

This extracts `'Item'` followed by a number with a decimal place and everything including 1 or 2 digit number, followed by another 4 digit number.

If there are many such patterns in the text you can use `str_extract_all` to get all of them.

Comment: when I run your code it works perfect, but when i run it on my WHOLE text  file, I also get result from first TABLE OF CONTENTS. I get this result - `Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition Item 9.01. Financial Statements and Exhibits SIGNATURES EXHIBIT INDEX EXHIBIT 99.1     Table of Contents        Item 2.02. Results of Operations and Financial Condition         On January 27, 2005`. But I want it after second (2nd) Table of contents. Do you know how can i fix it?

Comment: Is the 1st Table of contents always in uppercase? If that is the case you can use `stringr::str_extract(string, '(?<=Table of Contents)\\s+Item \\d+\\.\\d+.*?\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}')`

Comment: Yes it is always Uppercase if it is available. In such case, your code works well, but if TABLE OF CONTENT is missing, I do not find anything. The code and results are like - `stringr::str_extract_all(df$text[42], '(?<=Table of Contents)\\s+Item \\d+\\.\\d+.*?\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}')
[[1]]
character(0
`

Comment: If  old code is run, here is the issue - `stringr::str_extract_all(df$text[42], 'Item \\d+\\.\\d+.*?\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}')      [[1]] [1] "Item 8.01. Other Events. On April 8, 2005"  [2] "Item 8.01. Other Events.  .   SIGNATURES  INDEX TO EXHIBITS FILED WITH THE CURRENT REPORT ON FORM 8-K  EX-99.1 2 a2155762zex-99_1.htm EX 99.1       QuickLinks  -- Click here to rapidly navigate through this document  Exhibit 99.1 DENVER, COLORADO ;April 8, 2005 ` If you look here, You will see Item 8.01 is repeated.